# dropzone.js is not working inside angularjs partial view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js, image-upload

[Dropzone js](http://www.dropzonejs.com) is an awesome plugin used for drag & drop upload. I want it to implement in my angularjs project.

Please find the scenario, which I have tried

I have included

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="/target" class="dropzone"></form>
```

inside partial view, while executing the page in browser  tag itself removed from DOM.

When I include it in index.html page, it is working properly. Please let me know how to make dropzone working, inside angularjs partial view.

Comment: did you get an solution for this yet?

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem. For reproduction, the dropzone selector `new Dropzone('#selector')` is not working as aspected on default templates. The selector fails on async. loaded views. There is a easy fix. Init dropzone on a form will enforce dropzone template rendering correctly.

#### View

```
<form id="dropzone-form" class="dropzone"></form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#dropzone-form', {
    url: "/file/post"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you included:

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="/target" class="dropzone"></form>
```

The issue may simply be that you included the above form "inside" another form.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).